# wal2json with the existing WAL (Postgres)

Tags: postgresql, wal

I have some WAL files in my current system, Do we have any solutions to use these files with wal2json? (no base backup, no archive WAL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a logical replication slot from at least that far back, it is not feasible.  The catalogs must have retained enough information to reconstruct the table structures being replicated as-of the time of the WAL files it is decoding.  Preserving that data is one of the things a logical replication slot does.